# $\mathcal{BC}^n(X,E)$ is not closed in $\mathcal{BC}(X,E)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $X$ be open in $\mathbb{K}$, $E$ some Banach space, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I have the following exercise:

> Show that  $$\mathcal{BC}^n(X,E):=\left(\left\{f\in\mathcal{C}^n(X,E)\colon f^{(j)}\in\mathcal{B}(X,E),\,0\leq j\leq n\right\},\Vert \cdot\Vert_{\mathcal{BC}^n}\right),$$
>   where  $\Vert f\Vert_{\mathcal{BC}^n}=\max_{0\leq j\leq n}\Vert f^{(j)}\Vert_\infty$, is not closed in $\mathcal{BC}(X,E)=(\mathcal{B}(X,E)\cap\mathcal{C}(X,E), \Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty)$.

Is this abusus of notation? It is meant to show that the underlying set of $\mathcal{BC}^n(X,E)$ is not closed in in $\mathcal{BC}(X,E)$, am I right?

Any hint on how to do that? E.g., is there a sequence that, on $X=\left]0,1\right[$, converges unformly to $u\colon t\mapsto \sin(1/t)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: start by doing it for $E = \mathbb{R}$.  A convenient way to produce such a sequence is to take a sequence of smooth functions $v_n$ converging in $L^1$ to some function $v$ that cannot be a derivative (e.g. a step function).  By dominated convergence it is enough  for the convergence to be pointwise almost everywhere and with a uniform bound.  Then by considering the integrals $u_n(x) = \int_0^x v_n(t)\,dt$ you get a sequence of smooth functions converging uniformly to $u(x) = \int_0^x v(t)\,dt$ which is continuous but not differentiable.

It is really helpful to draw yourself some pictures.

Comment: Thank you, that did help. I am being introduced to integration theory at the same time... Is there a general result on why the functions given by the integrals varying in the upper bound are converging uniformly to $u$? The functions introduced by integrating up to a variable upper bound have not been treated systematically yet. Is there a name/subtheory for these functions?

Comment: Basically, the map $v \mapsto \int_0^\cdot v(t)\,dt$ is a bounded linear operator from $L^1$ into $BC$.  A function $u$ can be written as $u(x) = \int_0^x v(t)\,dt$, for some $v \in L^1$, if and only if $u$ is [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_functions); in this case $u$ is a.e. differentiable and $u' = v$ a.e.  This is the standard "Lebesgue version" of the fundamental theorem of calculus.